# Book recommendations to self-study calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm looking for book recommendations to self-study calculus, but not sure which books to refer to (even if there are online lectures on youtube then that'll also work).
(I'm in 9th grade if that helps)

But i also want to climb my way up from there to more advanced topics like real and complex analysis, so are there any analysis books that a 9th grader can understand with basic calculus knowledge?